# Lock PDF while drawing lines using touch

Tags: c#, pdftron, pdfnet

I'm using PDFtron for a Win 10 app. I'm building my custom in house tools for drawing and text. I know I have the controls but I prefer building my own. I know that when executing the sample, and drawing a line using the touch mode, the pdf control doesn't flip the page because it is locked. I've tried to investigate how this happens but I don't see it anywhere in the controls sample project. Does anybody know how to lock the control when drawing by touch?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

So this did the trick...

```
  internal void UnFreeze()
    {
        _pdfViewer.SetZoomEnabled(true);
        _pdfViewer.SetScrollEnabled(true);
    }

    public void Freeze()
    {
        _pdfViewer.SetZoomEnabled(false);
        _pdfViewer.SetScrollEnabled(false);
    }
```